# Finding total mechanical energy, given the potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, virial-theorem

The average kinetic energy of a particle in a potential of the form
'$V(x, y)=x^{4}+4 x^{2} y^{2}+4 x^{3} y-2 y^{4}$'
is equal to $T$.

How can we find the total energy of the particle?

**My attempt:**

I know since a potential is given, so we've a conservative force acting here. Which implies that the total energy $E$ must be constant and may flow back and forth between kinetic and potential.

Also I observe that the potential at the origin is $0$ ,hence all the energy $E$ is kinetic at the origin.
Also $E= T + U$ where $U$ is the average potential energy.
That's all I could think to do.

I'd be grateful if someone helped or even pointed out anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the general equation $E=T+U$ and taking the average on both sides we get $\langle E\rangle=\langle T+V\rangle$; now the total energy is a constant, as you said, and the text says the average kinetic energy is just called $T$, so $E$ is given by $E=T+\langle U \rangle$.

To find the average of the potential, if I had a finite domain I would take the definite integral of the potential and divide it by the area of the domain. Here no domain is specified, so things look quite divergent or not well defined. It kinda makes sense, because at $x\rightarrow+\infty$ $U\rightarrow+\infty$, so you would need an infinite total energy to reach infinity on the x axis.

Comment: Thank you, so is the question vague and can't be answered? $U\rightarrow+\infty$ reminds me of the potential of an infinite charged sheet in electrodynamics.

Comment: Yes, a domain should have been specified, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is a bit ill-defined so if the problem is really solvable I'd guess this is for a system of particles where you can get use of Virial theorem. You have the potential of

$$V = x^4+4x^2y^2+4x^3y-2y^4$$

and $F = -\nabla V$ therefore

$$<T> = \frac{1}{2}<\nabla V\cdot \textbf{r}>$$

$$\nabla V = ((4x^3+8xy^2+12x^2y)\hat{i}+(8x^2y+4x^3-8y^3)\hat{j})$$

$$<T> = \frac{1}{2}<\nabla V\cdot \textbf{r}> = \frac{1}{2}((4x^3+8xy^2+12x^2y)\hat{i}+(8x^2y+4x^3-8y^3)\hat{j})(x\hat{i}+y\hat{j})$$

Thus

$$<T> = <2x^4+8x^2y^2+8x^3y-4y^4>$$

total energy

$$<E> = <T> + <V> = <3x^4+12x^2y^2+12x^3y-6y^4>$$